# JOOQ - Fetch into custom POJO that does not have all properties

Tags: java, jooq

Assuming I have a result set with many fields, including id, first_name, last_name, age, etc.

Is it possible make a custom POJO with only specific fields I care about and fetch into it, (without changing the select / specifying each column), or manually mapping them, so I would end up with something like:

```
class User {
    public long id;
    public String name;
}

dslContext.select().<some conditions>.fetchInto(User) // or something other than fetchInto
```

This is just an example, the real thing would have quite a few fields, so I'd rather not do it manually. Not sure if this is possible or not but thought I should ask.

Comment: You're already using the right methods and the right approach, yet you still seem to have doubts. Why do you have doubts? Did it not work when you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's possible.

jOOQ will map the result to your User class.